# how to embed nodejs application on client website?

Tags: node.js, express, embed, real-time

firstly sorry for not standard English. : D

I have a chat application using nodejs, expresss finished running on port 3000. So I want to embed in website application clients, then how?

I had to use ajax load, but can not be:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://localhost:3000/client/",
  success: function (data){
    jQuery('body').append(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: have you used socketio for building chat application ? if not then you need to.

Comment: I use nodejs, socket.io and express more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using socket.io at server side then you can get its reference at the client using below line (jquery required):

```
$.getScript(host+'socket.io/socket.io.js', function() 
{
  var clientSocket = io.connect(host);
  // ... do other stuff with your socket
});
```

Where **host** is your server host name e.g. `http://192.168.1.5:3000/` where your nodejs application is deployed.
For more information see [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events) for more client - server communication exposed events.

Comment: By the way ask yourself, how can I check the open on a 2 socket machine. that is open on the first 2 pages browser.

Answer (score 0):

try the example from http://book.mixu.net/node/ch3.html (it uses long-polling) once done with it use socket.io